# How to remove augmented data from test data

Tags: python, image-classification, image-preprocessing

I am working with this dataset https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/hxsnvwty3r/1 for object classification model like CNN. In the description of the dataset, I see in the description there are "4000 images. Of these, around 1800 are of distinct leaves, and the rest are prepared by zooming and rotating". Is there a way of removing the augmented images from my test dataset. As generally, the test data should not contain augmented data. Can anybody help in this regard? Thank you.